# What is the WebRTC method reattachMediaStream used for?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have been going over the WebRTC docs and I see two WebRTC methods where I am not sure I understand what the difference is: `reattachMediaStream` and `attachMediaSource`.

`attachMediaSource` This I get, you use it to attach a `MediaStream` to something like a `video` element.

HTML:

```
<video id="videoPlayer">
```

JS:

```
attachMediaSource(videoPlayer, mediaSource);
```

But when is `reattachMediaStream` used?

Looking at the [adapter.js](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js) code the WebRTC group provides, doesn't help much.

For Gecko it has:

```
  reattachMediaStream = function(to, from) {
    console.log("Reattaching media stream");
    to.mozSrcObject = from.mozSrcObject;
    to.play();
  };
```

For webkit it has:

```
  reattachMediaStream = function(to, from) {
    to.src = from.src;
  }
```

Looking at all the various examples out there also hasn't helped. I don't see anything using reattachMediaStream.

Is it attaching the video from one video element to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: the `reattachMediaStream` method allows you to attach the same media stream to multiple video elements.
For a usage example, have a look at [this page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/59a06670b5d3b3e4bf18bf8490bcd83dff96a8cd/samples/js/apprtc/index.html), at line 350:

```
function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    console.log("Remote stream added."); 
    reattachMediaStream(miniVideo, localVideo);
    attachMediaStream(remoteVideo, event.stream);
    remoteStream = event.stream;
    waitForRemoteVideo();  
}
```

In this example the method is used to show a preview of the local video in a small window in the right bottom corner of the page.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I couldn't find anything Googling. Looks like that was at the bottom of the search results page. :)

Comment: Also I'm thinking this is just a helper method provided by WebRTC via their adapter.js file to get around browser inconsistencies in attaching streams to videos and not part of the WebRTC spec itself.